# Change SQL table/column names in query using c#

Tags: c#, sql, parsing, object, graph

I am looking to provide a Web API similar to Facebook's FQL interface.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

My idea is to create a mapping of real SQL tables to fake ones, with nice friendly names etc, and then apply a condition to the query submitted to restrict access where needed.

My problem comes in find/replacing the real table/column names with the fake ones. Obvioiusly a find replace is a bit lame - and could be worked around.

My plan is to "read" the posted query, interpret it into an object graph of sorts, then recreate the query swapping in the relevant names and appending my mandatory conditions for the table in question.

Does anyone have any ideas on a better way to do this OR some tips on creating an object graph of the query? I have tried traditional lexer/parser techniques but I am struggling to make the code obviously readable. Is there something I could use pre-made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into creating your own Abstract Syntax Tree which you use to interpret the request sent to you. If you're able to build a complete syntax tree with this (see what expression trees can do for LINQ) you must be able to build something that translates your AST to the FQL you need.

There's a lot to find on how to create your own AST using parser generators etc. It depends on how much time you want to invest in this and how extensible you want everything to be.

Comment: This was my initial path. I have somewhat of an AST tree generator, but the complexity of basic SQL is quite hard for a first timer like me. I can code sufficiently but im learning about AST trees as I go.

Long term I plan to create a library which I can pass in an XML config file defining the table mappings/constraints. That way I can create a parser for any DB related project I have. I may also opensource the library if it seems useful to others.

Comment: When thinking of an AST, try to keep it simple. Make it work first for 80% of your work and add features afterwards. An AST is not easy to create especially not on the first try. Good luck!

Comment: I have found this very true :)

My current treeBuilder will work for select queries but I trip up when it comes to subqueries "(...)". I guess I'll just have to keep at it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create friendly Views of each table:

```
create view dbo.tableAView as
select id as UserIdentifier,
       fname as UserFirstName,
...
...
from tableA
```

Info on views: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214068(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: I will look into this now. I hadn't thought of doing this since I want to restrict the functionality offered over the Web API (to protect the server).

Comment: Views would make the SQL match the tables, but I have to expose some fields to the view if I wish to restrict the data returned. This is not what I want.